# DateTickUnit with roll

Tags: java, jfreechart, scaling

I want use DateTickUnit from JFreeChart to scale date axis. Can someone explain me on simple example how it works with rollUnit and roll multiple?

I write something like this to scale time but I am not sure how it works.

```
DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", locale);

TicksUnits = new TickUnits();
units.add(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.SECOND, 1, DateTickUnitType.MILLISECOND, 50, f2));
units.add(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.SECOND, 5, DateTickUnitType.SECOND, 1, f2));
units.add(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.SECOND, 10, DateTickUnitType.SECOND, 1, f2));
units.add(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.SECOND, 30, DateTickUnitType.SECOND, 5, f2));
```

Constructor of object

```
 /**
  * Creates a new unit.
  *
  * @param unitType  the unit.
  * @param multiple  the multiple.
  * @param rollUnitType  the roll unit.
  * @param rollMultiple  the roll multiple.
  * @param formatter  the date formatter (<code>null</code> not permitted).
  *
  * @since 1.0.13
  */
  public DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType unitType, int multiple,
           DateTickUnitType rollUnitType, int rollMultiple,
           DateFormat formatter)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: It is default JFreeChart class and I want to know how it works on example.

Comment: Your question is overly broad. You might review the [source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateTickUnit.html) and try to focus your question.